# How to conditionally rename or overwrite copies of files?

Tags: batch-file

I need a `.bat` file to copy all files in the spool printing directory and paste them to the `output` folder on my desktop. What I already have:

```
@echo off & setlocal
mkdir "%userprofile%\Desktop\"%date:/=-%" 
del /f /s /q "C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS\*.*" >nul 2>nul
rem Group all file names by size
for /R %%a in (%userprofile%\Desktop\"%date:/=-%"\*.spl) do call set size[%%~Za]=%%size[%%~Za]%%,"%%~Fa"
rem Process groups
for /F "tokens=2* delims=[]=," %%a in ('set size[') do Call :Sub %%a %%b
Goto :Eof
:Sub
If "%~3"=="" (Set "size[%1]="&goto :EOf)
processing %*
Keep %2
Shift&shift
:loop
Del  %1
"C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS\*.spl" "%userprofile%\Desktop\%date:/=-%" >nul 2>nul
if not "%~2"=="" (shift&goto :loop)
```

I expected the `.bat` file to continuously copy files to the `output` folder, and in case of equal file name, to check difference by size and if so, copy to `output` folder. And that if the file was unaltered, to delete it. But when I run it, nothing happens. What is wrong?

The `.bat` file has to run continuously, waiting for the printer to create a file in the spool directory. When present the `.bat` file should detect it and copy to `output` folder. But the problem is the printer will generate another file with the same name and extension. The `.bat` needs to copy this to the `output` folder (but since it has the same name the `.bat` file needs to rename it first).

So if a file already exists by the name of `005.spl` (in `output` folder) and there's another file (of equal size) by the same name, the `.bat` file has to copy and past it to the `output` folder as for example `005(1).spl`. This is what I don't know how to do.

Comment: The quoting of your Pathes is unbalanced. Also I don't see how any files could be in the newly created folder with the date on the Desktop. You clear the spool files initially and then try to group an at that time presumably empty folder. The 2nd last line with a wildcard can't be executes.

Comment: @LotPings, they were told about that and many other things earlier, before ignoring the advice, deleting the question and reposting it!

Comment: @Compo" a thousand will fall on your side and ten thousand on your right, but you will not be hit "

What makes us human? The stupidity or intelligence? 

If you have time to disturb, you also have time to help! I remade the question because the first was confuse.

Kisses!

Comment: @LotPings i'll check ot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off & setlocal

rem Get 1st argument. Undefined spool to disable Delete SPL Mode.
set "spool=%~1"

rem If cmdline argument passed, do delete mode else do copy mode.
if defined spool (
    echo Delete SPL Mode
    echo.
    set "func=DeleteSpl"
    if not exist "%spool%\*.spl" (
        >&2 echo No spl files found.
        exit /b 1
    )
    set "output="
    rem Optional pause so you can manually exit the console if wanted.
    rem pause
) else (
    echo Copy SPL Mode
    echo.
    set "spool=%systemroot%\System32\spool\PRINTERS"
    set "output=%userprofile%\Desktop\%date:/=-%"
    set "func=CopySpl"
)

rem Timeout for loop cycle.
set "sleeptime=1"

rem Make output folder.
if defined output if not exist "%output%" mkdir "%output%"

:loop
setlocal

rem Group all file names by size.
for /R "%spool%" %%a in (*.spl) do call set size[%%~Za]=%%size[%%~Za]%%,"%%~Fa"

rem Check size[ is valid.
2>nul >nul set size[|| (
    endlocal
    >nul timeout /t %sleeptime% /nobreak
    goto :loop
)

rem Process groups.
for /F "tokens=2* delims=[]=," %%a in ('set size[') do call :%func% %%a %%b

endlocal

rem Avoid looping for delete mode.
if "%func%" == "DeleteSpl" exit /b 0

>nul timeout /t %sleeptime% /nobreak
goto :loop

exit /b 0


rem Copy spl files from spool to output.
:CopySpl
    setlocal

    rem Skip 1st argument.
    set "skip1="

    for %%a in (%*) do (
        if not defined skip1 (
            set "skip1=1"
        ) else (
            call :SaveAs "%%~a" "%output%\%%~NXa"
        )
    )
exit /b 0


rem Renames to output with an index number.
:SaveAs
    setlocal
    set "pathname=%~DPN2"
    set "name=%~N2"
    set "i=0"

    rem Check size with all files in output folder.
    for %%a in ("%output%\*.spl") do if "%~Z1" == "%%~Za" exit /b 0

    :NewNameLoop
    set /a "i+=1"
    if exist "%pathname%(%i%).spl" goto :NewNameLoop

    rem Copy with indexed name to output.
    echo Keep: "%~NX1" as "%name%(%i%).spl"  %~Z1
    copy "%~1" "%pathname%(%i%).spl" >nul 2>nul
exit /b 0


rem Delete spl in output based on size.
:DeleteSpl
    setlocal

    rem Skip 1st and 2nd argument.
    set "skip1="
    set "skip2="

    for %%a in (%*) do (
        if not defined skip1 (
            set "skip1=1"
        ) else if not defined skip2 (
            set "skip2=1"
        ) else (
            echo Delete: "%%~NXa"
            del "%%~a"
        )
    )
exit /b 0
```

This code copies the spool files to an output folder.
If no spool files, exits with errorlevel 1.

The call to the `:CopySpl` label sets `skip1` to undefined. 1st loop
will detect `skip1` as undefined and will set it to `1` so following
loops will pass over this undefined condition.

All files will be a renamed `copy` with an index number.

The spool folder may have certain permissions set so consider that
when you run the script.

Using a loop to keep `copy` going forever. Timeout `sleeptime` is 1 second.

The `:SaveAs` label is called to `copy` with an index number
i.e. `filename(index).spl`.

The script also accepts an argument to a output folder to remove files
that are of same size i.e. removes duplicates by size. This mode does
not use a endless loop.

Comment: michael_heath Firstly thanks for the help! Can you check my last edit?

Comment: Added the `:SaveAs` label to call for indexed rename on `move`.

Comment: Worked fine! Just one more point. The `.bat` needs to run continousily until i close it. I tried to do it with `goto` but didn't worked. What can i do to keep it running unstopabble?

Comment: I added a endless loop which sleeps 1 second for each loop cycle.

Comment: Almost! The script can't delet the spool files, because if delet, the printer will be not able to print. I tried to change the `move` to the `copy` but didn't work. It's already deleting the files of the spool.

Comment: Sorry, I do not have the printer to test this behavior. I can modify the answer at request though making the printer work with it is your task to solve. If this is just backup `*.spl` files, then perhaps `copy` files and skip `del` and let the printer do the deleting as it may usually do.

Comment: Yes, it's a backup. The printer must remove the files in the spool by it self.  But i guess that i can't just remove `del` lines, because it's part of the command. i Just tested deleting `del "%%~a"` and changing the `move` for  `copy`. But ocurred a problem:
When the file in the spool is different but has the same name as the file is already in the output folder, the batch copy it endlessly. Ex.: if `001.spl` already existis in the output folder, and the printer create another `spl` with the same name, the printer save it in output folder endlessly as `001(1).spl` `001(2).spl`, `001(3).spl`.

Comment: Updated answer. Only option that may work with the printer is to copy all spl files (rename if needed).  Done. Deleting spl files with duplicate content in the output folder is safer and may need to be handled separate if that is suitable. The latter could be a separate script and executed on a earlier dated output folder to avoid conflict.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173220/discussion-between-michael-heath-and-karen).